# Appium - unable to swipe / scroll, android + java

Tags: java, appium

Inside file 1, `foo.java`

```
bar driver = new bar(getDriver());
driver.click(bar.btn);   // this works
driver.test();           // this does not
```

Inside file 2, `bar.java`

```
public bar(WebDriver driver) {          
    super(driver);                  
}


public void test(){
    click(btn2);     // this works too, able to access webdriver
    swipe(0.95, 0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 2.0); //errors out
    //scrollTo(xpath);  // no error but no action
  }
```

The "click" and "swipe" both resolve to the same class file with all the classic webdriver available keywords.  If click works and can access the webdriver class file, how come I am left with an error when I try to swipe?

Error:

> "Not yet implemented."

If I use `"scrollTo(xpath);"` instead of "swipe", I do not get any errors, but nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo needed two params.  Works now.